# in_array, needle and haystack are both an array

Tags: php

Is there a function to check an array for some values? I have 2 arrays, 1 with file extensions and 1 with mixed stuff. In_array is only working with a string.

Thanks already!

example of the file:

```
picture21474.png
```

Allowed extensions:

```
$extensions = array('gif', 'jpg', 'png');
```

I explode on a dot on the file. But when you use explode, the file is being set to a array(). Now i wanne check if the file extension is legit. Something like in_array($extensions, $explodedFile)

Comment: And what would that function do exactly? See if all items in needle are in the haystack? At least one item?

Comment: Please provide more info. What do you want to search in which array?

Comment: can you post what you've tried / sample data source...

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 functions that might help you with this:

1. `array_intersect ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )`
   array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.
   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php
2. `array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )`
   Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.
   https://www.php.net/array_diff

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$intersect = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
echo count($intersect) . ' elements in array2';
```

If you want to check if all elements from `$array1` are in `$array2`, do:

```
if (count($intersect) == count($array1)) {}
```

Edit:

If you want to check if file's extension contains in extensions array, do:

```
$filename   = 'picture21474.png';
$extensions = array('gif', 'jpg', 'png');
list($name, $extension) = explode('.', $filename);

if (in_array($extension, $extensions) ) {
  // extension is valid
}
```

Edit 2:

Valid getting of file's extension:

```
$filename = 'picture21474.png';
$info     = pathinfo($filename);

if (in_array($info['extension'], $extensions) ) {
  // extension is valid
}
```

Comment: I now use array_intersect and it works fine. Is your way bether or faster? Or is it just a prefference a programmer has?

Comment: Using `array_intersect` is faster than looping an array. However if you want to check if extension is valid, it's better to use my second solution.

Comment: Can u explain the code for me please? Ive heard from the list function, but dont know what i does and the PHP.net site is only in english, so hard to understand what it does with that short of information

Comment: `list()` function assigns elements from an array on the right to the variables defined inside `list()`. So if `explode` function returns: `array(0 => 'picture21474', 1 => 'png')` then `$name` gets `0` value and `$extension` gets `1` value.

Comment: Aaaaaa! Very nice functions! Thanks! But, there is a small issue: what if a user uses the file name picture.21474.png, then the array get 3 type of values: 0 = picture, 1 = 21474, 2 = png

Comment: Thanks! Works great! 1 more question: i have a var with the file name to check my function, but i also use is_file(). Now a error will ocure everytime. Is there an easy way to set a temporarily file to my script?